# SQL: consultar y componer resultado

Tags: sql, sqlite

Buenas, estoy intentando hacer una consulta para SQLlite, en ella tengo una tabla desde la que hago referencia a otras tres tablas llamada Statu_Actual semejante a la tabla siguiente.

```
tabla: *Statu_Actual*
id_Puesto | id_Clientes | id_Vhiculo | Status
1           1                  1         on
2           5                  4         on
3           null               null      off
4           2                  3         on 
.           .                  .          .
```

Los valores  de id_Clientes,id_Vhiculo,Status son los indices de las otras Tablas.

Necesito Hacer las misma tablas pero con valores de cada una de las tablas

```
tabla: *Statu_Actual*
id_Puesto | id_Clientes     | id_Vhiculo | Status
A110      |   Juan Prez     |   fiat     |    on
A105      |   Pedro zuares  |   Corsa    |    on
A106      |   null          |   null     |    off
A96       |   null          |   null     |    off
```

en Resumen esta es la consulta que deseo realizar.

Hice esto pero me repite algunos valores al colocar la ultima linea de código.

```
from Puestos As P inner join Status_Actual As S ON P.ID_PUESTOS=S.ID_PUESTO
                  Left outer join Clientes as CL ON S.ID_CLIENTE = CL.ID_CLIENTE
        [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí][1]          Left outer join VEH_CLIENTES as VC ON 
                  s.ID_CLIENTE=VC.ID_CLIENTE;
```

Esta es la base de dato

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: agrega por favor los querys que probaste

Comment: y por favor aclara sobre que base de datos

Comment: Este fue el ultimo que utilice que mas o menos me dio resultados:

Comment: select 
   Id_puestos AS Id,
   Piso, 
   Nombre AS Name,
   Puesto,
   Left_puesto AS Left,
   Top_Puesto as Top,
   Heigth_Puesto as Heigth,
   Width_Puesto as Width, 
   S.ocupacion As Status,
   S.Id_cliente As Id_Cliente, 
   cl.fam_cliente ||' ' || cl.nom_Cliente As Cliente, 
   s.Id_Vehiculo As Id_Vehiculo, 
   vc.Vin_Auto As Placa
from Puestos As P Left outer join Status_Actual As S ON P.id_Puestos=S.ID_Puesto Left outer join clientes As CL ON S.Id_Cliente = CL.Id_Cliente Left outer join Veh_Cliente as VC ON CL.Id_Cliente=VC.Id_cliente;

Comment: aclaro la PUESTOS tiene las ubicaciones geométricas de una serie de estacionamientos portante es única; CLIENTES: Registros únicos de Clientes;  VEH_CLIENTE: registro de los vehículos que tienen cada cliente, un cliente puede tener varios clientes; STATUS_ACTUAL: ocupación del momento, donde un vehículo puede estar a la vez en un puesto. Pero cuando hago la consulta me indica que un puedo esta ocupado por dos o tres vehículos a la vez.

Comment: por favor usa el boton [edit]. ordena y agrega la informacion a la pregunta. tene en cuenta que no sabemos que tenes ni que necesitas. deja solo la informacion relevante, y mira los links que te pase en el primer comentario

Comment: Si tienes registro repetidos utiliza la clausula: GROUP BY. Si puedes añadir el SQL para crear tus tablas podremos probar a recrear tu problema / encontrar la mejor solución.

Comment: amigo esta es la base de datos https://www.dropbox.com/s/xif518lrhlxck1o/Estacionamiento.db?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añadiendo la clausula ***GROUP BY*** al final de tu consulta puedes agrupar por campos, por ejemplo, la consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM Puestos As P 
inner join Status_Actual As S 
ON P.ID_PUESTOS=S.ID_PUESTO
Left outer join Clientes as CL 
ON S.ID_CLIENTE = CL.ID_CLIENTE
Left outer join VEH_CLIENTES as VC 
ON s.ID_CLIENTE=VC.ID_CLIENTE
GROUP BY ID_PUESTOS;
```

Devuelve 536 registros, frente a los 600 obtenidos sin añadir esta última línea, evitando las repeticiones en el campo *ID_PUESTOS*.

Comment: Hermano eres el mejor, eso es exactamente lo que necesitaba. muchísimas gracias. tendré que leer bien todas las sentencias de sql para estar mejor informado. Mil Gracias

Comment: @J.Ramos No te olvides de votar / aceptar la respuesta como la mejor si resolvió tu problema. Un saludo.